# iOS UI Automation: assertion's error of text field (highlighted in red color) via CTAssertTrue

Tags: swift, ui-automation, assert, ios-ui-automation

During the automation of the email's changing case, there was a problem with the assertion of the element "
[text field highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7VTH.png) ".
**Can you please give some advices to assert this element?**

**How did we try to solve the problem:**

- via function "waitForText":

```
func waitForText(name: String) {
        waitForElementToAppear(app.staticTexts[name])
    }
```

"waitForText" function is short case of "waitForElementToAppear"'s implementation:

```
func waitForElementToAppear(_ element: XCUIElement) -> Bool{
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let expectat = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectat], timeout: 20)
    return result == .completed
}
```

- via function "waitForTextShort":

```
func waitForTextShort(name: String) {
        waitForElementToAppearShort(app.staticTexts[name])
    }
```

"waitForTextShort" function is short case of "waitForElementToAppearShort"'s implementation:

```
func waitForElementToAppearShort(_ element: XCUIElement) -> Bool{
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
        let expectat = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
        let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectat], timeout: 5)
        return result == .completed
    }
```

- via CTAssertTrue:

```
CTAssertTrue (app.staticTexts.element (match: .any, id: "Enter your email address"). exists)
```

Finding items with a UI tests recorder only displays the input field, but not required field.

Unloading elements via **po app.staticTexts** in test's runtime also does not give the desired results:

```
 StaticText, {{16.0, 130.0}, {288.0, 16.5}}, tag: "Enter your email address"
```

Used locators:

```
app.tables/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.staticTexts["Enter your email address"]/*[[".cells.staticTexts[\"Enter your email address\"]",".staticTexts[\"Enter your email address\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/.tap()
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved: just ask your developer to add some identifier to the required element - and assert it easily :)